# Power Query slow using parameter

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a long query in Power Query, here is the M syntax:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="LOGDATA"]}[Content],
    ChangeTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"POWER_AVG", type number}, {"TIMESTAMP", type datetime}}),
    Diff = Table.AddColumn(ChangeTypes, "Differanse", each PARAMETER-[POWER_AVG],type number)
in
    Diff
```

It's quite simple, it takes LOGDATA which is a table in Excel that has 2 columns (POWER_AVG and TIMESTAMP). Then it does a simple substract with a parameter called PARAMETER. The PARAMETER is loaded in a different query, but this is simply loaded from a table with 1 value.

For some reason, the query is very slow (like 10 seconds). I currently work with about 6300 rows but this should be a walk in the park. When I do this in Excel, the calculation is more or less instant for all 6300 value (I checked with graph).

What am I doing wrong? How can I speed up the Power Query?

Comment: 10 Seconds is too slow?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Perhaps it has something to do with the code in your query that creates `PARAMETER`. Just using some value as a Parameter in your equation executes in a fraction of a second for 10,000 rows.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot help you. What is the dataset you are bringing in, what is the expected outcome - other than speed, which as @horseyride pointed out, seems reasonable?